# Select tag is not rendering on Jsp

Tags: java, select, struts2

Before this I have used the struts 2 select tag successfully, but I am stuck to a problem now, my jsp is throwing an exception due to the select tag, I have created an array list which I am passing to the 'list' attribute of select tag, I have also defined getters & setters for that list and also for the name property element of the select tag, I'm getting following exception again and again for every select tag which I newly create.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'division':
The requested list key 'divisionList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

please help thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your ArrayList isn't in the right scope for your JSP page - we could help if you posted some code.

Comment: My problem is solved sir, when i create getter/setter by going to "Source" menu in my Eclipse Editor and select generate getters/setters, that problem occur but when i directly use shortcut key control+1 on property to create getter/setter it gives me proper output, sounds strange but it's true.

Answer (score 1):

I am successfully using this select tag in my application. There is no exception. Change the proper property names. If this does not solve your problem then send me your code and some more description.

```
<html:select style="width:192px" name="VForm" property="classificationName" >
     <html:optionsCollection property="comboList"/>
</html:select>
```

Thanks
Imran